# php grouping results from database, pushing between arrays

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, recursion, grouping

I am trying to group results from the database in PHP. 
So far I (almost) got it working just fine by using following code:

```
$results = $this->getRecords();
$records = [];

foreach($results as $record) {
$setOfData = [
 'name' => $record['name']
]
  $records[$record['id_category']][] = $setOfData;
}
```

Which becomes something like this:

[image]

Though what I really would like, is to have another array that describes the category name and then output the contents, like so:

[image]

I have tried something like pushing a new element into the array, but that makes the grouping go away.

```
$records[$record['id_category']][] = ['name' => $records['category_name'], 'records' => $setOfData];
```

What would be the best way to achieve this, using Recursive or can it still be done "simple"?

Comment: What is the content and structure of the source data (`$this->getRecords()`)?

Comment: Please do not use images. Edit your question and show the info as text. Images can't be copied and pasted, and make your question way to long vertically.

Comment: Edit your question and show the query used to gather the data, and also include the schema of the source tables. Tale a look at [SHOW TABLE CREATE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/show-create-table.html) to see how to display the table schema, then copy/paste as text into your question.